# MySQL appears after server restart

Tags: mysql, missing-data

We have MySQL database. The data in the database is automatically inserted from PLCs. The client says that sometimes part of the data is missing until restart of the MySQL Server. After that the data is there. My question is: IS IT REALLY POSSIBLE?

Comment: What means "part of the data": Are there rows of data missing or only columns? Did you forget to commit  your data?

Comment: Actually the updated status of the rows

Comment: The PLC doesn't support transaction mode. It uses auto comit

Comment: It's just as likely user has not refreshed whatever..